# Why does na.omit() not remove columns

Tags: r

`na.omit()` removes rows in matrices or data frames, but i was wondering why it does not have an option to remove columns instead of rows.

I am aware that there are solutions like:

`df[sapply(df, function(x) !any(is.na(x)))]` ([credits to Erik Iverson-3 from r forum](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/how-to-delete-columns-with-NA-values-td1839902.html))

But why does the r implemented function does not support it? I think is kinda consequentially  to implement something like an argument as following:

> na.omit(df, by.rows = FALSE)

Here some simple sample test Data if needed, intended output is removed columns 3 and 6:

```
df<-mtcars
df[5:15,6] <- NA
df[5:15,3] <- NA
```

Comment: "why" questions are often opinion-based if answerable at all, and not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: oh alright sorry then, i hoped there is a logical reason or something like this. Should i delete the question then? I'm pretty new to stackoverflow

Comment: You can wait to see if other people disagree with me. You can also try asking in the R Public chat room (access chat rooms in the upper right corner).

Comment: na.omit exists to delete incomplete observations, removing columns is a completely different thing conceptually.  It's just "geometrically" related.

Comment: I agree with moody.  That if using tidy data one would not usually want to do this.

Comment: with `purrr` you can try `modify_if(df,anyNA,~NULL)` or `df[] <- lapply(df,anyNA)` in base R

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Alright i think this is reasonable, i didn't think about it. It occured when i was exporting an excel to csv and i had some empty rows i wanted to remove. So i looked up na.omit() and i came up with that question, but it makes sense that the intended function is not to clean up badly saved data. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `na.omit` function is used primarily for processing data.frame objects for regression functions. Cases (i.e. rows) need to be omitted in order to run the math-machinery for regression calculations. You can see the various choices to be made from the na.action parameter for lm, but this applies to many other types of regression. It's basically designed to allow `lm` to succeed where it would otherwise produce a useless result. The formula specification is the device for leaving out columns.

> na.action
>   a function which indicates what should happen when the data contain NAs. The default is set by the na.action setting of options, and is na.fail if that is unset. The ‘factory-fresh’ default is na.omit. Another possible value is NULL, no action. Value na.exclude can be useful.

The choice of na.action may affect the output of `predict`. Notice that the default for predict.lm is different: `na.action = na.pass`.